# A TCP Quote Server and Client in Twisted Python fault

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

I'm going through a book called "Twisted Network Programming Essentials rev.2" and I have a problem with example of quote server. I've copied the code from the book but when I launch server and then client I'm having an **error** in client-side terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quoteclient.py", line 45, in <module>
    reactor.connectTCP("triptrck.com", 8000, QuoteClientFactory())
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here's the code for the **quoteclient.py**:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class QuoteProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendQuote()

    def sendQuote(self):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.quote)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Received quote:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class QuoteClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, quote):
        self.quote = quote

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QuoteProtocol(self)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection failed:", reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection lost:", reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

def maybeStopReactor():
    global quote_counter
    quote_counter -= 1
    if not quote_counter:
        reactor.stop()

quotes = [
    "You snooze you lose",
    "The early bird gets the worm",
    "Carpe diem"
]

quote_counter = len(quotes)

for quote in quotes:
    reactor.connectTCP("triptrck.com", 8000, QuoteClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I do understand that the problem is I'm not passing a '*factory*' parameter in the '**QuoteProtocol**' call inside '**buildProtocol**' function of '**QuoteClientFactory**' class. But I have no clue what should I pass in there. Also i figured out that '**QuoteClientFactory**' call in the bottom also would need a second parameter '*quote*', so I've tried to put it like that:

```
for quote in quotes:
    reactor.connectTCP("triptrck.com", 8000, QuoteClientFactory(quote))
reactor.run()
```

The result was unexpected, for me. The **error** in client-side terminal disappeared, instead I've got **this**:

```
connection lost: Connection was closed cleanly.
connection lost: Connection was closed cleanly.
connection lost: Connection was closed cleanly.
```

Could anybody explain me what's going on? Why do we need that '***init***' with '*factory*' and '*quote*' and what should i pass in there?

**P.S.:**
I've also had a problem in first example in the book, the echo factory server, where for some reason data wouldn't go through and I've had to change '*transport.write*' to '*sendLine*' using '**LineReceiver**' instead of '**protocol.Protocol**'. Maybe it has to do something with that too?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured out that the initial **error** was caused because of that '*quote*' missing in '*reactor.connectTCP*'. But still the problem with '*transport.write*' not working correctly persists.

UPDATED: Just now noticed that i wrote '*qoute*' instead of '*quote*' in **quoteserver.py**, so the problem was my inattention